# How to convert timelogs (timestamps) in a dataframe into seconds (integer)?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime, time

I have a dataframe with columns: Text, Start time, and end time.
All three of them are strings.
[The dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3uS9.png)
What I am focused on currently is that, I need to convert the elements of Start & End columns into number of seconds. That is, converting 00:00:26 into 26. Or 00:01:27 into 87. etc.

The output elements need to be in int format.

I have already figured out the way to convert the string of timelog into proper timestamps

```
datetime_str = '00:00:26'

datetime_object = datetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%H:%M:%S').time()

print(datetime_object)
print(type(datetime_object))
```

Output:
00:00:26
<class 'datetime.time'>

But how do I convert this 00:00:26 into an integer 26.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're manipulating a *df*, you can simply use [`Timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) & [`total_seconds`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) from [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) :

```
df["Start_2"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["Start"]).dt.total_seconds().astype(int)

df["End_2"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["End"]).dt.total_seconds().astype(int)
​
```

Output :

```
print(df)

      Start       End  Start_2  End_2
0  00:00:05  00:00:13        5     13
1  00:00:13  00:00:21       13     21
2  00:00:21  00:00:27       21     27
3  00:00:27  00:00:36       27     36
4  00:00:36  00:00:42       36     42
5  00:00:42  00:00:47       42     47
6  00:00:47  00:00:54       47     54
7  00:00:54  00:00:59       54     59
8  00:00:59  00:01:07       59     67
9  00:01:07  00:01:13       67     73
```

Comment: that worked, tyvm!